# Is this code relying on function call order undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I have to build a `LPoint3f` with 3 arguments which are the result of `dgi.get_int32() / 100.0`. In Python I can rely on the calling order:

```
LPoint3f(dgi.get_int32() / 100.0, dgi.get_int32() / 100.0, dgi.get_int32() / 100.0);
# values are correct
```

When translating this code to `C++` I wrote:

```
LPoint3f pos(dgi.get_int32() / 100.0, dgi.get_int32() / 100.0, dgi.get_int32() / 100.0);
// incorrect values sometimes, correct others
```

However, this works:

```
x = dgi.get_int32() / 100.0;
y = dgi.get_int32() / 100.0;
z = dgi.get_int32() / 100.0;
LPoint3f pos(x, y, z);
```

Is code #1 undefined behavior?

Comment: I doubt this is your problem. What does `get_int32()` do?

Comment: @NacibNeme Does it have side effects?

Comment: No, it shouldn't have any side effects.

Comment: It must have side effects, otherwise x y and z would be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Order of function calls in C++ is unspecified. If your calls get_int32() have any side effects, i.e. modifying some internal value, then you will not get the same result as in Python. The code is not undefined but it will not produce reliable values.

Comment: Will produce reliable non desired values